# Continuity of a conditional two variable function

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus, functions, continuity

Let

$f(x,y)= \begin{cases} \frac{1}{y^2} & \text{if} \hspace{0.2cm}  0<x<y<1 \\
                       -\frac{1}{x^2}  & \text{if} \hspace{0.2cm} 0<y<x<1 \\
                         0 & \text{otherwise}. 
                        \end{cases} $

I need to examine when it would be continuous and when not, I think it would be continuous on $(0,1)^2 \land x \neq y$. On the other side, for y and x close to zero it would be unbounded (it would go to either $\infty$ or $-\infty$, I think).

Further, the other interesting cases would be where,  $x \lor y =1$, $x=y$? I think I would be needing two dimensional limits, but I do not know how to calculate them here.

Edit: I could draw it, but I still do not know how see whether it is discontinuous or not for x=y?
[image]https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Xbm8.jpg

Comment: Please don't [delete and repost your question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3926719/290189).  To attract attention to your problem, your should use bounty.  Please contribute more until you're eligible for that.

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會 : oh no, the deletion was unitentional. I wanted to edit sth, and accidentally hit *delete* instead of edit, and I didn' know whether the question would still be seen as active, If I hit *undelete* afterwards, or only be archived

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會 I remember you also making a comment below the first post in regards to finding sequences. Could you elaborate please, which sequence here would be useful, for examining the continuity at the points $x=y$?

Comment: A self-deleted question can be undeleted by question author by clicking "undelete".  See https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3919051/revisions as an example.

Comment: make a 3d sketch of the problem.  imagine the shape, and you'd know what sequence to choose.

Comment: Is the sequence method the only method to show discontinuity? Isn't there another approach? I would argue with  the left and side hand limit, for x=y, they would be $1/y^2$ resp $-1/x^2$ but the function for x=y would be zero. Would this reasoning work?

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會: I think I could draw it now https://imgur.com/a/QVUxgDw, but still do not know how to find this sequence?

Comment: to show discontinuity at a point, you first need a sequence in the domain converging to the point of discontinuity.  then think about the function values.  in your function definitions, boundary points of the domains are evaluated to zero.  so  you need a non-zero sequence that doesn't tend to zero to complete your argument.

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會: Thank you! for the boundary 1, would the sequence $\frac{x}{x+1}$ work as this would converge to 1? but how to find a sequence for x=y argument?

Comment: Note that the domain is two-dimensional.  You set $(x_n,y_n)_n$ tens to what?

Comment: shouldn't it be to $(x_n, y_n)_{n}$ either to (x,x) or to $(y,y)$?

Comment: you argue that $\{(x,y) \mid x = y \lor xy(x-1)(y-1)=0 \}$ is the set of points of discontinuity.  you are partly correct.  Note that you need to consider $(x,a)$, $(a,y)$ where $a = 0$ or $a = 1$.

Comment: would this mean that for $a=0 \lor 1$ fixed  it wouldn't matter which values we had for x, it would be uncontinuous throughout all values of $x$?

Comment: you have to prove this using a nicely chosen convergent sequence (in the interior of the domain) $(x_n,y_n)$